# Android SQLite how to move mainActivity (login process)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, autologin

I used this method, it works when data is in database, and it's not working when database is empty.

```
 private boolean checkDataBase() {


        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(String.valueOf(dataBase), null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            checkDB.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Next.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        return checkDB != null;


    }
```

I am new to Android development, this is my first android application.
The application contains three `Activities`(splashscreen, login, main_activity).

My question is:

- How to launch `MAIN_ACTIVITY` if `database` contains value(login value), if not launch Login activity?
- What is the condition?
- Where do I use it?

Comment: please first of Register activity used and store data in database. and after using login activity work using database thru login.

Comment: i used the above method

Comment: first of  try store data in database using Register Activity thru..

Comment: pls check this link all of yr solution Database thru working...http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Answer (score 2):

use this method to query your database.

`public boolean login(String username, String password) throws    SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE  WHERE USERNAME=? AND PASSWORD=?",
                new String[] { username, password });
        if (mCursor != null) {
            if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do not use the SQLite database to store the login value. If you want to store the login value rather use Shared Preferences. You can read up about the Shared Preferences [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

private final int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000; // Splash screen timer

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_layout);

    // This method call delays the execution of the activity 
    // by 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds)
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            Intent intent;

            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("LOGINPREFS", 0);

            /* Checks if the user has ever logged in
             * If not, a login screen is displayed.
             * LOGGED_IN would be the name of the shared preference key, 
             * which would have been set on the login activity, 
             * only if the login is successful
             */
            if (sharedPrefs.contains("LOGGED_IN")) {
                intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("student", student);
            } else {
                intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
            }

            startActivity(intent); // Starts a new activity

            finish(); // Close this activity
        }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    } // Disables the back button
}
```

Comment: for SQLite what to do?

Comment: What do you need SQLite for?

Comment: Did you figure it out?